# How can I train a DDPG with Keras to echo points back based on its observations?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, reinforcement-learning, keras-layer

I am trying to train a reinforcement learning model to echo a point back to me using [`keras-rl`](https://github.com/matthiasplappert/keras-rl).

My code is shown below, using a world shape of 20x20.

```
import numpy as np
import rl.core as krl


class EchoEnv(krl.Env):

    def __init__(self):
        self.shape = np.array([20, 20])
        self.desired = np.random.rand(*self.shape.shape)

    def step(self, action):

        action = np.clip(action, 0, 1) * self.shape
        self.action = action

        observation = self.desired

        dx = action - (self.desired * self.shape)
        distance_to_goal = np.sqrt((dx**2).sum())

        done = distance_to_goal < 1

        reward = -distance_to_goal

        # observation, reward, done, info
        return observation, reward, done, {}

    def reset(self):
        self.desired = np.random.rand(*self.shape.shape)
        return self.desired
```

Each iteration, the `observation` provided is the current random `self.desired` value. (The agent *should* learn to return this value immediately.) The `done` value signifies whether or not the selected point is within a reasonable margin of error. The reward provided is `-distance`, so that it should choose a point closer to the goal to maximize this value.

```
from rl.agents import DDPGAgent
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
from rl.random import OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, concatenate, Flatten, Activation
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam

actor_n = 3
critic_n = 3

env = EchoEnv()
nb_actions = len(env.desired)
observation_shape = (nb_actions,)

actor = Sequential()
actor.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,) + observation_shape))
for _ in range(actor_n):
    actor.add(Dense(16))
    actor.add(Activation("relu"))
actor.add(Dense(nb_actions))
actor.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
actor.summary()

action_input = Input(shape=observation_shape, name="action_input")
observation_input = Input(
    shape=(1,) + observation_shape, name="observation_input")
flattened_observation = Flatten()(observation_input)
output = concatenate([action_input, flattened_observation])
for _ in range(critic_n):
    output = Dense(32)(output)
    output = Activation("relu")(output)
output = Dense(1)(output)
output = Activation("linear")(output)
critic = Model(inputs=[action_input, observation_input], outputs=[output])
critic.summary()

memory = SequentialMemory(limit=10000, window_length=1)
random_process = OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess(
    size=nb_actions, theta=.15, mu=0, sigma=.1)
agent = DDPGAgent(
    nb_actions=nb_actions,
    actor=actor,
    critic=critic,
    critic_action_input=action_input,
    memory=memory,
    nb_steps_warmup_critic=100,
    nb_steps_warmup_actor=100,
    random_process=random_process,
    gamma=.99,
    target_model_update=1e-3
)
agent.compile(Adam(lr=1e-2), metrics=["mae"])

agent.fit(env, nb_steps=100000, visualize=False, verbose=2)

agent.test(env, nb_episodes=10, visualize=True)
```

The actor is a `Sequential` model, beginning with an initial `Flatten` layer. Some number (in this case, `actor_n = 3`) of `Dense` layers with 16 nodes are added, followed by ReLU activation. Finally, a `Dense` layer with `nb_actions` nodes (in this case, `2`) and sigmoid activation is added.

The critic begins with an `Input` layers for both actions and observations, and the observation is `Flatten`ed. The output is defined as the `concatenate`d action and flattened observation inputs. Some number (in this case, `critic_n = 3`) of `Dense` layers with 32 nodes are added, followed by ReLU activation. Finally, a `Dense` layer with `1` node is added with a linear activation function.

The random process used is the [Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process), with `mu = 0`, `sigma = 0.1`, and `theta = 0.15`.

Finally, the actual `DDPGAgent` is created using the actor, critic, random process, and other parameters (shown in the code above). It is compiled with an [`Adam`](https://keras.io/optimizers/#adam) optimizer with a learning rate of `0.01` and the mean absolute error metric.

---

In theory, this agent should quickly learn that returning the values observed will provide the highest reward. However, there are two major issues.

#### Learning Inconsistency

Once in a while, randomly, this will work. It will begin to return actions extremely close to the observations provided, getting a reward in the range `[-1, 0)`, which is the best reward possible.

However, the important thing to note here is "randomly". Usually, it will train for tens of thousands of steps, not learning this simple property. Occasionally, by chance, it seems to work.

#### Unchanging Output

If I cancel the training before it has found the optimal strategy, the algorithm repeatedly guesses the same incorrect value. My prior experiences with machine learning give me reason to believe that the agent should try to optimize its strategy even during testing, trying to maximize reward and end the episode quickly rather than "giving up" and choosing the same value repeatedly.

---

There seems to be no issues with my environment. Thus, the issue must be somewhere in my DDPG model. My intuition tells me that it must be something with the layers, either in the actor or the critic. However, the issue very well could be with any of the other parameters, including in the random process or the optimizer.

**How could I go about solving these issues?**